# MySQL Function getting Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create the below function in MySQL but getting syntax error.
I am not able to find the solution, would be grateful for some help

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`pro`(depart_id int) RETURNS varchar

BEGIN
     DECLARE title varchar;

if depart_id = 1 then 
   set title='IT Department';

else if depart_id = 2 then 
   set  title='HR Department';

else 
   set title='Admin';
end if;

return title;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What is your syntax error?

Comment: `varchar` needs a length

Comment: @10086 This is the error i got "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
         DECLARE title varchar;
    
    if depart_id = 1 then 
       set' at line 3"

Comment: have you set the DELIMITER  before the function * - DELIMITER $$

Comment: @juergend gave length, still facing the same issue

Comment: @juergend yes , obviously, i agve DELIMITER before the function

Comment: Use MySQL WOrkbench to find the errors. It highlights the problematic parts.

Answer (score 2):

You have several syntax errors in your script:

- `varchar` must have a length
- You should define `DELIMITER $$` first
- It's not `else if`, but `elseif`

Try this;)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`pro`(depart_id int) RETURNS varchar(10)

BEGIN
     DECLARE title varchar(10);

if depart_id = 1 then 
   set title='IT Department';

elseif depart_id = 2 then 
   set  title='HR Department';

else 
   set title='Admin';
end if;

return title;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, The error was the third point you specified, the first two points I had already given